# Writing a whole input stream at once in log using slf4j

Tags: java, logging, inputstream, slf4j

I am trying to write a input stream to the log file using slf4j. But i am able to write line by line whereas i want the whole input stream to print in logs.

For eg : If file has content
**"ABC /n
XYZ"**

Right now i am able to print
**INFO ABC
INFO XYZ**

Whereas i want
**INFO ABC
XYZ**.

Code snipped it tried

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.loggingInputStream));
            String readLine = null;
            try {
                while ((readLine = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    log.info(readLine);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is not complicated, just use a stringbuilder, collect those lines and log them once instead of log each of the lines.

Comment: Yup, Realized it bit late. Did in the exact same way. String buffer = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());